# How to convert a project from microsoft visual studio 6.0 to Visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am using microsoft visual studio 6.0 to develop my projects, and I also have installed Visual Studio 2017 and i need to convert a project from microsoft visual studio 6.0 to Visual studio 2017 by changing project properties

Comment: The project file format will have changed enough that it'd be easier to open the project in VS 2017 and let it do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade a project created in an earlier version of Visual Studio, just open the project in the latest version of Visual Studio. Visual Studio offers to upgrade the project to the current schema.

> If you choose No, the project doesn't get upgraded. For projects
>   created in Visual Studio 2010 and later, you can still use the project
>   in the newer version of Visual Studio. Just set your project
>   properties to continue to target the older toolset.
>
> If you choose Yes, then the project gets upgraded in place. It can't
>   be converted back to the earlier version.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Upgrade C++ projects from earlier versions of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)